# Error type: LoadXML Description: Incorrect XML

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I need a scheduler in MVC 3 application. 
In Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Data()
        {
            List<MyCalendar> data = _iManageVendors.GetAllCalendarDetails();
            return View(data);
        }
```

The data here will retrieve all values from database and its View Data.cshtml is

```
@model dynamic
           @{
               Response.ContentType = "text/xml";    
       }
<data>
    @{ foreach (var myevent in Model) {
        <MyCalendars id="@myevent.Id">
            <StartDate><![CDATA[   @String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}",myevent.StartDate) ]]></StartDate>
            <EndDate><![CDATA[     @String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}",myevent.EndDate) ]]></EndDate>
            <Text><![CDATA[        @myevent.Text]]></Text>
        </MyCalendars>
     } 
     }
</data>
```

Its an xml view.. and
Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}
<head>
<script src="http://www.codeproject.com/Scripts/dhtmlxscheduler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://www.codeproject.com/Scripts/dhtmlxscheduler.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">
            html, body
            {
                height:100%;
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
            }
        </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        debugger;
        alert(scheduler);
        scheduler.config.xml_date = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i";
        scheduler.init("scheduler_here", new Date(2013, 6, 1), "month");
        scheduler.load("/Home/Tasks");

        var dp = new dataProcessor("/Home/Save");
        dp.init(scheduler);
        dp.setTransactionMode("POST", false);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
    <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
        <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">
            &nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">
            &nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_today_button">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_date">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right: 204px;">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right: 140px;">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right: 76px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_header">
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

But when I load the page, view of calendar is coming but some error in xml.. Can anyone pls help me in solving this??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, when I provided the same name event,start_date,end_date,text,.. as in the dhtmlxscheduler.js .